# How to delete entries from redis stream really?

Tags: redis, stream

I would like to delete specific entries from redis stream, but the documentation said XDEL only marks the entries as deleted, the memory is not released. They are really deleted when all the entries in the macro-node are marked as deleted. Then, How should I delete entries from redis stream really and meanwhile release memory? I am using redis 6.2.6, thank you.

I was trying to XDEL to delete entries, but I don't know how to verify they are deleted really or not.

Comment: Why do you want it to be physically, i.e. *really*, deleted? Once you call XDEL, you can no longer access the item, no matter it's physically or logically deleted.

Comment: Our project relies on Redis stream to exchange messages among different processes, and it can produces millions of new items in a short time and save them into stream, but our consumers can not handle these items so fast, then, sometimes, an item could be in pending list. When one consumer is spare and picks this item from pending list, this item disappear early in stream(since we set the maxlen of stream), then error happens. we got (None, None) from stream by the item ID, then, I would like to delete some useless items physically to save this item more time.

Answer (score 1):

[XDEL](https://redis.io/commands/xdel/) will not do what you want. This is just not something it does. If you think that it should, you can always open an issue requesting the feature at https://github.com/redis/redis/issues. No guarantees there, of course, and this isn't exactly the fastes solution to your problem.

I will say that I agree in principal with the comment by [for_stack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5384363/for-stack) that this shouldn't be that big of a deal. But you know your needs best. Perhaps you are working in a very constrained memory environment—like some sort of edge or IoT thing. Or maybe there are regulatory or security requirements that you must follow.

So, here's a possible solution. If the nodes you want to delete are at the bottom of the stream (i.e. are the oldest) you can use [XTRIM](https://redis.io/commands/xtrim/) instead. It has an option to remove an approximate amount of entries—leaving macro nodes intact—or to remove an exact amount and adjusting the macro nodes accordingly.

Removing the exact amount is the default behavior.

```bash
redis.cloud> XTRIM key MAXLEN 1000
redis.cloud> XTRIM key MINID 132456-2
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I would like to remove items according to item ids, they could not be in one macro node. I know this could increase the memory, since the stream will became fragmented, but my purpose is to save some items in a long time(More info in my answer for for_stack). I considered to increase the maxlen of the stream, but I don't know if it is good or bad for our project. Current, if it is not possible to remove item really, I will try to increase maxlen.